# food here (without an article)

Tags: grammar, articles

Is it common to use ' food here is good.'?
I wonder whether it is right to use this description without an article'the'. I think this sentence is to emphasize that the food in this specific place is nice. So I am  confused.

Answer (score 0):

*Food here is good* is perfectly grammatical, but you're right that *The food here is good* is more idiomatic.

When we're making a comment about what is available or to be experienced in a place, we usually particularize it with "the".

Comment: Thanks ! Dear Colin, could you please tell me whether English native speaker use 'food here' more frequently in daily communication？ Or we could use it in some casual talking? Does the emphasis  change when we use 'food here is good' instead of ' the food here is good'?

Comment: No, I can't think of a context where we are likely to refer to "food here" without the article.